# WPF Visual Studio: Main window does not scale to fit Windows screen

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

After reinstalling Visual Studio, the main window in any WPF projects ceased to be scaled to the scale selected in Windows. I have set the scale of the screen to 125% and before the window and all the text in it were increased in size. Now, it is the main window that remains the same size as at 100% scale. How to fix it?

The only thing I did besides reinstalling was to set the value according to the instructions from here: [url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/visualstudio/general/cannot-find-resource-named-error)

```
setx VSXAML_DISABLE_ON_DEMAND_RESOURCE_VALUES 1
```

---

Example:

**Interface scale 125%**

Main Window and Dialog Window

**dimensions of both windows - `Height="450" Width="800"`**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Scale **150%**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**And I remind you that the size of the windows is the same.**

What can I do about it?

---

**Main Window:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        Background="DarkGray">
    <Grid Background="#222222">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="btn" Grid.Row="1" Content="Button"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Dialog:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApp.Dialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Dialog" Height="450" Width="800" Opacity="0.5">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Test Text" FontSize="25"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hi,@denisnumb. Which version of Visual Studio did you reinstall? I tested your code in Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (version 16.10.2) and both windows are scaled normally. Have you made any other settings?

Comment: @HuiLiu-MFST I am currently using the community version 16.11.4. I didn't make any changes, just reinstalled the visual studio Also tried resetting settings but didn't help

Comment: Hi,@denisnumb. Has your problem been solved? Could you try to reinstall Visual Studio?

Comment: @HuiLiu-MFST I asked the same question in ru StackOverflow and gave the answer there. However, this is not a complete solution. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1337036/wpf-visual-studio-%d0%93%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0-windows/1337361#1337361